# How to export a Mongoose model from a CommonJS module in TypeScript NodeJS app

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, typescript

I have a model defined in `models/user.ts`

```
import mongoose = require('mongoose');
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ ... });
var User : mongoose.Model<any> = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

Normally in JavaScript, in order to use the model `User` in a NodeJS app `app.js`,

In JavaScript I would ordinarily use `module.exports = User` from `./models/user.js`, followed by `require` from the file I want to use `User` from.

e.g.

```
var user = require('./models/user')
```

however this is not recognized in TypeScript (I get transpiler errors), and neither is

```
import User = require("/models/User")
```

although that would work if I was exporting, say a class, from `/models/user.ts` like

```
export class User { ... }
```

What is the syntax to export the mongoose model from `./models/user.ts` and import it from another file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> syntax to export the mongoose model from ./models/user.ts and import it from another file?

## Export

```
import mongoose = require('mongoose');
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ ... });
var User : mongoose.Model<any> = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
export = User;  // EXPORT
```

## Export Non Type Script

```
import mongoose = require('mongoose');
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ ... });
var User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
export default { User };  // EXPORT
```

## Import

```
import User = require("./models/User"); // Note the `.` to make it relative.
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to simply prepend `export` to your model.

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ ... });
export default var User : mongoose.Model<any> = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

Or if you want to stick with the CommonJS syntax you can `export.modules = User;`